# Reporting Services/Manager Access

Tags: reporting-services

I am Running SQL Server R2 on my local Windows 7 Professional 64-bit machine.  The only way I can open Report Manager is if I turn UAC off.  If I set UAC to the recommend level and run IE as admin I get the following error:

The report server cannot open a connection to the report server database. The log on failed. (rsReportServerDatabaseLogonFailed) Get Online Help Could not load file or assembly 'BCMLogon, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Failed to grant minimum permission requests. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131417) 
 Required permissions cannot be acquired.

I have read a lot of different tips, but none work for me...  I prefer not to turn UAC off.  Any suggestions to correct the permissions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure if you ever figured this out, but I ran into the same thing and found this blog post that helped: http://completedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/01/network-provider-issues-and-sql-server.html. Kind of an odd thing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the 'Reporting Services Configuration Manager' and then check the Database tab. There you can set up the ReportServer database to be used with your installation and the credentials (user) used to access it. Make sure you do your changes using admin account (e.g. 'sa').

Please keep in mind that members of BUILTIN/Administrators are no longer granted admin access to the SQL Server installation so you will need a SQL server login with sysadmin rights.

Once you click Apply and have no errors there - you should be able to access your local installation no problem. Right click on IE to 'Run as Administrator' and then point it to http://localhost/reportserver or http://localhost/reports

Comment: I had the same problem and this answer sent me in the correct direction. We use a different user from 'sa', but changing the Credential in the Database section of Reporting Services Configuration Manager to use that user corrected the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Responding due to finding this question in Google.

I had this issue recently with SQL Server 2014 Standard Edition, using Reporting Services. I was able to access the report configuration homepage, but I was unable to access any reports.

SQL Server Reporting Services is attempting to use BCMLogon.dll in System32 to login to the database. This driver is a wireless 'Logon Provider' specific to Dell computers. The error that presented itself for me had this signature:

library!ReportServer_0-2!15d0!01/10/2017-16:10:59:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.LogonFailedException: Logon attempt for user 'XXXX' failed., Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.LogonFailedException: Log on failed. Ensure the user name and password are correct. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'BCMLogon, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Failed to grant minimum permission requests. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131417)

The server I had this configured on isn't using its wireless card, so the solution was to navigate to System32 and rename 'BCMLogon.dll' to 'BCMLogon.bk'.

Reporting services worked fine for me after this.